# ASP.NET MVC - How to load static code (content) from another class or control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity, sitefinity-mvc

I am new to MVC and I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for, probably because of not using the correct terminology to search.

I am trying to load a static menu navigation in my ASP.NET MVC View (which is a widget template in Sitefinity CMS).

In **Web Forms**, this was an easy task by registering a User Control in the widget template like this:

```
<%@ Register TagName="SecNav" TagPrefix="CustomNav" Src="~/CustomWidgets/SecondaryNav.ascx" %>
```

And then in the body of my Widget template I could call the control like this:

```
<ul>
  <CustomNav:SecNav runat="server" />
</ul>
```

What is the equivalent method of the above in ASP.NET **MVC View**?

Comment: In MVC you have Partial Views, but you will need to provide the correct model to that view. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @VeselinVasilev, I'll look that up.  I have a bunch of Views (for my Detail pages) and they all share the same secondary navigation code. I was wondering how to template the navigation and utilize it in my Views, so it can be managed/edited in one location instead of various places.

Comment: Okay, so I am able to pull and display my navigation with this in my Detail View: @Html.Partial("~/Mvc/Views/Shared/BookstoreSecNav.cshtml"), but is there a better way by not specifying the full path? Maybe by adding a @using statement?

Comment: You can try just @Html.Partial("BookstoreSecNav") and Sitefinity will automatically look for it in the Shared folder.